# Oracle SQL - Query Hanging When Minimizing Select Statement

Tags: sql, performance, oracle

I have a sql query, which hangs when changing the select statement from * to only one column. Where could it possibly hang? Isn't that supposed to result faster, since I request only 1 column, instead of 50?

`select *
from table1 t1, table2 t2
where t1.id1 = t2.id2 and t2.columnX = :x`

`select t1.column1 from table1 t1, table2 t2 where t1.id1 = t2.id2 and t2.columnX = :x`

p.s. the columns have indexes.

Regards

Comment: possible that the "fast" query is just pulling from cache?

Answer (score 1):

On the surface, it appears there should be no difference between the results. Start by comparing the [EXPLAIN PLAN](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/ex_plan.htm) output for each query. If the cost is the same, then there's something else beyond the queries themselves that's at issue here. As @tbone states in the comment, it could be something as simple as caching.